# Chaining a variable number of promises (CompletableFuture) in Java

Tags: java, promise, reactive-programming, future, completable-future

Given a list of functions, where `Context` is some custom type:

```
List<Function<Context, CompletableFuture<Context>>> preprocessors;
```

I need to get a `CompletableFuture<Context>` having executed every single of those function in order feeding the async result of every iteration into the next one. So I need a general solution (for a variable list size) for the following statement with 3 elements in the list:

```
Context context;

CompletableFuture<Context> promise = preprocessors.get(0).apply(context)
    .thenCompose((c) -> preprocessors.get(1).apply(c))
    .thenCompose((c) -> preprocessors.get(2).apply(c));
```

Any ideas?

To get rid of indices, the above could also look like this:

```
Iterator<Function<Context, CompletableFuture<Context>>> it = preprecessors.iterator();

Context context;

CompletableFuture<Context> promise = it.next().apply(context)
    .thenCompose((c) -> it.next().apply(c))
    .thenCompose((c) -> it.next().apply(c));
```

Still, how do I generalise this further into a variable element count?

Comment: Perhaps some usage of Stream.reduce() - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are only interested on the result for the last CompleteableFuture (promise), then you could just get each iteration promise and compose upon it.

Taking either an index or foreach loop you could use the following code snippet for your purpose:

```
CompleteableFuture<Context> promise = CompleteableFuture.completedFuture(context);
for(Function<Context, CompletableFuture<Context>> preprocessor: preprocessors) {
  promise = promise.thenCompose(ctx -> preprocessor.apply(ctx));
}
```

Comment: Sometimes one just misses obvious things :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to do this with reduce like this:

```
        CompletableFuture<Context> res =
            preprocessors.stream()
                         .reduce(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(context),
                                 (future, processor) -> future.thenCompose(processor::apply),
                                 (old, current) -> current);
```

The accumulator (the second param) gets receives the future and the processor and produces the next future. So the combiner (the third param) can safely throw away the "old" future and just return the new one.

Untested! It may not work as advertised :)

Comment: Calling `future.get()` is a no-go. It has a potentially of indefinitely blocking the even-loop thread where this whole thing of mine is running.

Comment: Yes.. I put a better version in the answer above.

Comment: Actually, your untested disclaimer tells it all: it is difficult to comprehend what is going on without actually writing tests proving correctness and then trusting them. Writing tests is essential, but it is sort of better if code can be understood independently of those :) Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like RxJava might be useful:

```
    Flowable.fromIterable(preprocessors)
            .map(function -> function.apply(context))
            .flatMap(Flowable::fromFuture)
            .subscribe(c -> {
                // Whatever it is you want to do with the context that is returned
            });
```

Though I must admit I'm not entirely sure if this will ensure sequential execution of all futures

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: Requires RxJava as a dependency and my lib has none so far. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `reduce()` it seemed to be hard to work around the special handling for the first element, and impossible to guarantee sequential handling. Using just regular Java you could write

```
List<Function<Context, CompletableFuture<Context>>> preprocessors;
Context context;
Iterator<Function<Context, CompletableFuture<Context>>> itr = preprocessors.iterator();

CompletableFuture<Context> promise = itr.next().apply(context);
while(itr.hasNext())
    promise = promise.thenCompose(c -> itr.next().apply(c));
```

Comment: Thanks, very similar to the foreach solution below. But that one is more straightforward.